# How can I determine if a Bash variable or function has been defined *again*?

Tags: bash, function, environment-variables, environment

Let's say I have a variable in existence in a Bash environment:

```
variable1="zappo"
```

Now, let's say that I define that variable again, with exactly the same value:

```
variable1="zappo"
```

By what means could I determine in a shell script that the second definition had taken place? I am concerning myself with how a Bash variable definition *would* change the variables in the environment, as opposed to how it *did* change the variables in the environment.

If you want to consider an implementation, imagine a script which one sources to set up an environment of variables. Imagine that the script has been sourced previously and that some of the variables it defined have been changed. I need the second sourcing of the script to list the variables that it has defined, in spite of the fact that some of those variables may have been in existence with the same values.

Generalising on this concept, can you conceive of a way of listing the functions that are re-sourced? Let's say that there is a script consisting of a library of functions. This script is sourced initially and then one of the functions in the library script is changed, necessitating the re-sourcing of the library script. How could such a library script list the functions that it has re-defined, even if many of the re-defined functions are not different to how they were defined previously?

Here is some code that could offer some inspiration for the function list:

```
#!/bin/bash

initialListOfFunctionsInEnvironment="$(typeset -F | awk -F"declare -f " '{print $2}')"

function1(){
    variable1="zappo"
}

function2(){
    variable1="zappo"
}

finalListOfFunctionsInEnvironment="$(typeset -F | awk -F"declare -f " '{print $2}')"
functionList="$(diff  <(echo "${initialListOfFunctionsInEnvironment}" ) <(echo "${finalListOfFunctionsInEnvironment}") | grep -E '^(<|>)' | awk -F"> " '{print $2}')"

echo -e "\nlist of functions loaded:"
echo "${functionList}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to suggest just an idea. The code is not tested and not optimized at all and is intended just as an example. The regex used in `egrep` is to be adapted to your coding style on function declaration.

The idea is to use an helper function like this to source your library

```bsh
function re-source {
    for i in `cat $1 | egrep -o 'function\s+\S+\s?(\(\))?' | sed 's/function//'`; do
        if [[ typeset -F $i ]]; then
            local old_$i=$(typeset -f $i);
        fi
    done

    source $1

    for i in `cat $1 | egrep -o 'function\s+(\S+)\s?(\(\))?' | sed 's/function//'`; do
        if [[ diff <(typeset -f $i) old_$i ]]; then
            echo "$i updated";
        fi
    done
}
```